# VB.NET/ASP.NET - Calendar Control - Selecting years

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar, date

How is it possible to let the user choose the year from the Calender Control in ASP.NET?

Currently, the calender allows you to scroll left to right (previous month - next month), so, if for example, someone was born in 1970, he would need to click as far as 1970 to select his date of birth.

How is it possible to overcome this?

Current calender:

[image: Calendar]

Comment: Use a different control that supports that option.

Comment: It doesn't support it out of the box. Here is an example of how to add it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229445/Customizing-the-ASP-NET-Calendar-Control

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, it's not supported out-of-the-box. However, there are other options.

You could use:

- jQuery UI's ***[Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)***
- AJAX Control Toolkit's ***[Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)***

OR

You could simply create a custom control, as ***@Jack Pettinger*** was alluding to, that does exactly what you want by extending the ASP.NET Calendar control.